# What is a "Vintage Ski Sweater" and how is it different from a normal sweater?

Tags: clothing, skiing

I'm confused as to what separates "Vintage Ski Sweaters" from other sweaters.

My initial thought was that is would be ski themed or that it would be designed to be light weight with good thermal protection so that it fit under normal skiing attire.  However, after looking at them they look more like every day sweaters.

Comment: Lots of stuff is called vintage.

Comment: At least a 50% higher price tag than the non-vintage equivalent :-)

Comment: Search Google images and you will get a pretty good idea of what it means.

Comment: In the UK before 2002 the [C&A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%26A) shops sold ski clothing that included sweaters with colourful patterns. They are probably considered vintage. C&A still has shops in Mainland Europe, I do not know if they still do  skiwear.

Answer (score 3):

A "Vintage Ski Sweater", should be considered any ski sweater of at least five various types depending on how people define the word *vintage*:

> [Adjective](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vintage)
>
> vintage ‎(comparative more vintage, superlative most vintage)
>
> 1 (attributively) Of or relating to a vintage, or to wine identified by a specific vintage.
>
> 2 (attributively) Having an enduring appeal; high-quality
>
> 3 (attributively) Classic (such as video or computer games from the 1980s and early 1990s, or old magazines, etc.).
>
> 4 (attributively) Of a motor car, built between the years 1919 and (usually) 1930 (or sometimes 1919 to 1925 in the USA).
>
> 5 Of a watch, produced between the years 1870 and 1980.

Personally when I hear the term used in this sense with clothing I generally take it to mean that they are of a classic design and are generally more pricy than other styles.